# Custom mysql alpine image not loading init.sql from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d mounted as a volume

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to create a customer mysql image from base image as alpine. I have installed the necessary packages for mysql via apk through dockerfile. My requirement is i want to run a fresh instance of mysql_alpine and create and modify tables in the db. My data files are located in /var/lib/mysql/ mounted as a volume and my init.sql is mounted as a volume into /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/. Following is my dockerfile

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk --no-cache add mysql mysql-client && \
    addgroup mysql mysql && \
    mkdir docker-entrypoint-initdb.d && \
    mkdir run/mysqld && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /run/mysqld && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql && \
    chmod -R +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ && \
    mysql_install_db --user=mysql

 ENV "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=  " \
     "MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql" \
     "MYSQL_USER=test" \
     "MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword"

 VOLUME ~/mysql/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ && \
        ~/mysql/db/:/var/lib/mysql/

 CMD /usr/bin/mysqld --user=mysql
```

After i build the container when i run the conatiner with the command:

```
docker run -d -p 3307:3306 --name mysql_alpine mysql_alpine
```

only the db starts but there is no init.sql file inside docker-entrypoint-intidb.d/ folder and so, the file never got loaded when initializing the db

My init.sql file which is not getting mounted into docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder inside the container:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mysql;

USE mysql;

CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO 'testdata'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to fix your volume section, as :

```
 VOLUME ~/mysql/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ && \
        ~/mysql/db/:/var/lib/mysql/
```

is not correct, check the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume), instead you should use `COPY` instead:

```
 COPY mysql/init/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
 COPY mysql/db/ /var/lib/mysql/
```

And you need to make sure that `mysql` directory is on the same level as your `Dockerfile`.